# An inequality for inner product space: $\|a+b\|+\|b+c\|+\|c+a\|\le\|a\|+\|b\|+\|c\|+\|a+b+c\|$

Tags: inequality, inner-products

In an inner product space show that the following inequality holds:
$$\|a+b\|+\|b+c\|+\|c+a\|\le\|a\|+\|b\|+\|c\|+\|a+b+c\|$$
I figured LHS and RHS are two different upper bounds on $\|2a+2b+2c\|$ using the triangle inequality in two different ways, but I can neither prove it, nor find anything like it.

Comment: It's not true that $||b+c||+||c+a||\le||c||+||a+b+c||$. Just put $c=0$ for a counterexample.

Comment: @TonyK Oh, thanks! I just seem to have spent too much time on it

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2148636/1508) is a proof for the complex numbers. It translates easily to a proof for inner product spaces.

Comment: [This](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/167685/absolute-value-inequality-for-complex-numbers/167741) is a splendid discussion on this inequality. There are some insightful perspectives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [Hlawka's inequality](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HlawkasInequality.html). We have to show that
$$\|a\|+\|b\|+\|c\|-\|a+b\|-\|b+c\|-\|c+a\|+\|a+b+c\|\geq 0.$$
We multiply both sides by $\|a\|+\|b\|+\|c\|+\|a+b+c\|>0$ (if it is zero the inequality is trivial).
We note that in a inner product space we have
$$\|a+b+c\|^2+\|a\|^2+\|b\|^2+\|c\|^2=\|a+b\|^2+\|b+c\|^2+\|c+a\|^2.$$
Thus, we add
$$\|a+b\|^2+\|b+c\|^2+\|c+a\|^2-\|a+b+c\|^2-\|a\|^2-\|b\|^2-\|c\|^2\geq 0$$
to our product and after some algebraic manipulation it reduces to
\begin{align*}
&(\|a\|+\|b\|-\|a+b\|)(\|a+b+c\|+\|c\|-\|a+b\|)\\
&+(\|b\|+\|c\|-\|b+c\|)(\|a+b+c\|+\|a\|-\|b+c\|)\\
&+(\|c\|+\|a\|-\|c+a\|)(\|a+b+c\|+\|b\|-\|c+a\|)\geq 0
\end{align*}
which holds because, by the triangle inequality, in each of the three terms, both factors are not negative.

Comment: I don't think proving $\|x+y+z\|+\|x+y\|+\|y+z\|+\|z+x\|-\|x\|-\|y\|-\|z\|\ge0$ implies Hlawka's ineq.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool I edited my answer.

Comment: I guess the multiplier is all plusses

Comment: @TheMightyM Good point!. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: It must be said that Hlawka's inequality isn't necessarily true for a normed $\mathbb{R^n}$ whose norm isn't derived from a dot product: see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2487167/305862).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Since both sides are positive reals, it suffices to show $(\text{LHS})^2\leq(\text{RHS})^2.$