# Hlawka's inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, normed-spaces, inner-products

So here's the Hlawka's inequality where $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ belong to an inner product space:
$\|\alpha + \beta\| + \|\beta + \gamma\| + \|\gamma + \alpha\| \leq \|\alpha\| + \|\beta\| + \|\gamma\| + \|\alpha + \beta + \gamma\|$ 
I know the original proof as is stated in *Analytic Inequalities* by *D.S. Mitrinović*. We multiply it by the right side and after simplifying it and using triangle inequality, it is done.
My first idea for proving this inequality was to square both sides, and regroup the result and then prove the inequality for each group. something like the second proof in [here](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/Hlawka.shtml).
 That proof only holds for complex number, but the author has said that it can be generalized to vectors in an inner product space.
So that's where I'm stuck. It is easy for complex numbers. But I couldn't get any further on the general case.
In summary I want to show that the following inequality holds:
$
\|\alpha + \beta\|.\|\gamma + \beta\| \leq \|\alpha\|.\|\gamma\| + \|\beta\|.\|\alpha + \gamma + \beta\|
$

Comment: A proof for inner product spaces is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3649697/42969, as pointed out in response to your previous question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4684717/42969.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that proof. I just wanted to know if there is a proof for the inequality stated in the end of OP. @MartinR